# Problems with taxonomy quick edit box

Tags: custom-taxonomy, quick-edit

i've some problem with customization of quick edit box in a custom taxonomy page.

This is my code:

```
function lnw_quick_edit_custom_box($column_name, $screen, $name) {

if ( $screen !== 'edit-tags' ) return;

if ($column_name == 'special_star') {

?>
<fieldset>
    <div id="my-custom-content" class="inline-edit-col-special_star">
        <label>
            <span class="title"><?php _e('Special Star', 'my-theme'); ?></span>
            <span class="input-text-wrap">
            <select name="term_meta[special_star]" id="special_star_val">
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Sì</option>
            </select>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<script>
jQuery('a.editinline').on('click', function(){

    var now = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('td.column-special_star').text();

    //console.log(now);

    if (now.charAt(0)=='S') {now_i = '1';};
    if (now.charAt(0)=='N') {now_i = '0';};

    //console.log(now_i);

    jQuery('#special_star_val').val( now_i );
});
```

```
add_action('quick_edit_custom_box', 'lnw_quick_edit_custom_box', 10, 3);
```

Code seems to work correctly because now and now_i variables are populated by correct values, but jQuery('#special_star_val').val( now_i ) don't select the right option of select field.

I don't understand why...

thanks a lot!
Danilo

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `<a href="#" class="editinline">#</a>` your `jQuery` should use `on()` to save memory. Add `.editinline` selector to attach the function (handler) to multiple elements (in this case — `<body>` children)

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.editinline', function(){

    var now = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('td.column-special_star').text();

    //console.log(now);

    if (now.charAt(0)=='S') {now_i = '1';};
    if (now.charAt(0)=='N') {now_i = '0';};look like this

    //console.log(now_i);

    jQuery('#special_star_val').val( now_i );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47fd3fnu/

If you have single, you can use `click()` which is a shortcut to `on('click', '...', '...')`:

```
jQuery('.editinline').click(function(){
     ..........        
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47fd3fnu/2/